# JSF Using Tab and Space keys to activate a h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

There're a lot of end-user web frameworks (Bootstrap being one of them) which make links look like buttons. However these two are not the same when it comes to keyboard navigation on a page: buttons can be pushed by `Space`, links will require pressing `Enter` to activate.

Given the fact that `h:commandLink` and `h:commandButton` are functionally the same on the server side, how can I make them to behave the same when using keyboard navigation? Which basically boils down to the question how to make `h:commandLink` to trigger the same action by both clicking the link and pressing the spacebar *without* rewriting `.xhtml` sources.

In my limited knowledge, possible options are employing event listeners or writing special tag wrappers or even a custom `ResponseWriter` to update each `ClientBehaviorHolder` in the tree. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My advice: **do change** the xhtml sources. Convert the links that look like a button to an actual button. This to keep things simple, and you have the option to still use command links (that look like links) if you want to. Don't try to work around the problem using JavaScript and annoy users that expect certain behavior when they press certain keys.

If you really can't change the xhtml and if you are OK with converting each command link to a command button, you could [override the renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605401/jsf-2-0-how-to-override-base-renderers-with-custom-ones) for the command link component and render them as a button. If you are on Mojarra, you could use the following renderer in your `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
  <renderer>
    <component-family>javax.faces.Command</component-family>
    <renderer-type>javax.faces.Link</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ButtonRenderer</renderer-class>
  </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

See also:

- [Buttons and links keyboard triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840375/buttons-and-links-keyboard-triggers)
- [jQuery - Trigger click event on links with spacebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433969/jquery-trigger-click-event-on-links-with-spacebar)
- [JSF 2.0: How to override base renderers with custom ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605401/jsf-2-0-how-to-override-base-renderers-with-custom-ones)

Comment: Haven't tried it, but do you think it's safe to override renderer of a library like Primefaces or similar? Imo there might be some logic inside which will be lost in that case.

Comment: I've tried with the core JSF command link. That worked for me. If you are using a `p:commandLink` you should be able to replace its renderer with the one of `p:commandButton`. Haven't tried that specifically though.